# semantics of "destroy object" in HRU model

Tags: formal-methods, security, formal-systems

In the access control model HRU there is the primitive request destroy object o which is only defined if o is an object in the current protection state which is not a subject. I am interested in why this restriction is necessary/useful.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, because it doesn't make sense in the practical context that they wanted the theory to model.  In practice, you can't destroy something that doesn't exist; and we think of subjects as existing forever (you can't destroy them).

Comment: But there is also the operation destroy subject. And the thing that I want to destroy exists, but it is additionally to being an object although a subject, which means that destroying it as an object lets it loose its subjectness. (We employ the convention from the original paper that every subject is also an object)